# mariadb, How to find the index of an element in an array in a stored procedure

Tags: arrays, stored-procedures, indexing, mariadb

I am writing a stored procedure, in the procedure I have an array ["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"]

I have a query that returns the day of the week, I would like to return the index of the returned day in from the above array.

I could write an IF THEN ELSE testing for each day, however is there a more elegant way of doing the same using built in functions?

```
    IF vcSOW = 'sunday' THEN
        SET intSOW = 0;
    ELSEIF vcSOW = 'monday' THEN
        SET intSOW = 1;
    ELSEIF vcSOW = 'tuesday' THEN
        SET intSOW = 2;
    ELSEIF vcSOW = 'wednesday' THEN
        SET intSOW = 3;
    ELSEIF vcSOW = 'thursday' THEN
        SET intSOW = 4;
    ELSEIF vcSOW = 'friday' THEN
        SET intSOW = 5;
    ELSEIF vcSOW = 'saturday' THEN
        SET intSOW = 6;
    ELSE
        CALL procLogError(vcCompKey, CONCAT("Invalid start of week:", vcSOW));
        LEAVE exitProc;
    END IF;
```

So if the returned day is "sunday", then the index returned would be 0, if "saturday" the returned index would be 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

```
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('monday', 'sunday,monday,tuesday,...');
+----------------------------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET('monday', 'sunday,monday,tuesday,...') |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  2 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('Junk', 'sunday,monday,tuesday,...');
+--------------------------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET('Junk', 'sunday,monday,tuesday,...') |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                                0 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, something like:

```
SELECT @dow := FIND_IN_SET(intSOW, 'sunday,monday,tuesday,...') - 1;
IF (@dow < 0) THEN
    CALL ...
END IF
```